# Minimize applications with a back arrow

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

When I click the back arrow, I would like to go back to the previous screen, but have the previous fragment running in the background.

I tried this:

`val start = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN) start.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME) start.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK startActivity(start)`

I would like the application to run in the background but not to leave it.

Answer (score 0):

**you can run fragment in background while you are in another activity**

```
finish()
```

this will finish the activity to the previous activity